# Formulario PHP con 2 acciones

Tags: php, isset

Quiero que al momento de dar clic en enviar,  mi formulario use la opción  form action ...

```
<form  action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php $invoice ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" alt="Subscribe">
```

pero también necesito que me busque en la base de datos y me asigne un invoice de acuerdo al último número de la base de datos.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
$consulta2 = "select max(idMembresia) + 1 as invoice from membresia";    
                        $result = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta2);    
                        while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $liga = $mostrar['invoice']; 
?>
         
         <?php
        }
}
```

Al final solo me termina haciendo unas de las 2 opciones. O el Isset o el Action

Comment: Tal vez podrías capturar el click en el botón de submit con javascript, hacer una petición ajax a una url que te devuelva el número de factura, asignarla al input del formulario y luego lanzar el submit.

Comment: Con Ajax, o [con la nueva API Fetch de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) podrías resolver esto con suma facilidad, y además, te olvidarás de la horrible recarga de la página cada vez que quieres mandar algo al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te falta cerrrar el formulario y por eso la variable $_POST['submit'] no esta llegando.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   $consulta2 = "select max(idMembresia) + 1 as invoice from membresia";    
   $result = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta2);    
   while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $liga = $mostrar['invoice']; 
   }
}

?>
         
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">  
 <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php $invoice ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" alt="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar dos acciones en un formulario PHP basta con poner dos botones de tipo submit con valor diferente

```
<form  action="archivo.php" method="post">  

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php $valor1 ?>" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php $valor2 ?>" >
</form>
```